# How to add values that are in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, methods

tonight I am working on homework dealing with Arrays! 
I thought this was going to be simple...and it probably is but I am lost.

for my assignment, I am having a program read a text file that has a bunch of integer values that represent the amount of students in a section of a particular course. with this text file I need to find the average of students, the min and max of the sections.

Now the assignment was not clear on particulars but what I am trying to do is this:

in the main method establishes some variables and the array, as well as call methods to perform the calculations and then return the values so the main method can print.

I am stuck at the part of adding each value together (so I can use it to calculate the average)

My overall question is, how do I add values together that are in a text file?

a kind of sub question is do I have to have a scanner class read the text file in each method?

I hope what Im asking is making sense and would be grateful for any clarification given :)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnrollmentStats 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{


    // Create array to hold enrollments
    double[] enrollment = new double [100];

    // decale int for number of elements actually used
    int count;


    // call method to read data into enrollment[] line by line and return count
    count = readLines(enrollment);

    // call method to calculate average class size
    sectionAvg (enrollment);

    // call method to calculate minimum class size
    sectionMin(enrollment);

    // call method to calculate max class size
    sectionMax(enrollment);

    // print results (count, average size, min size, and max size)
    System.out.println();

} // End main ()


// This method reads data from the file into the array and returns the number
// of elements it uses
public static int readLines(double[] line ) throws Exception
{
    int count = 0;

    java.io.File sections = new java.io.File("enrollment.txt");

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(sections);

    while( infile.hasNextLine() )
    {
        line[count] = infile.nextDouble();
        count ++;

        System.out.println(" count is" + count);

    } // End while

    return count;

} // end readlines

public static double sectionAvg (double[] registered ) throws Exception 
{
    return avg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these outside of your `main` method

```
// method to read data into enrollment[] line by line and return count
readLines(double[] enrollment) {
    // do something
}

// method to calculate average class size
sectionAvg (double []enrollment) {
    // do something
}

// method to calculate minimum class size
sectionMin(double[] enrollment) {
    // do something
}

// method to calculate max class size
sectionMax(double[] enrollment) {
    // do something
}
```

Try and implement the methods above. **Hint: The method signatures are not complete. You need a return type.** Then call the methods in your `main` like you did

```
count = readLines(enrollment);
```

Try and work it out first before you come and ask for help.  Mkae your question specific as to show you have made an honest attempt but your having problems with something specific and explainable

Comment: thanks for helping/responding.  I did try to work it out and ended up getting mad and deleting it all. what you said did not really make sense to me. so I am just going to go back and read over the text again, hopefully I will pick up something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

check this...

I put these values in text file prog2test.txt as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog2
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("prog2test.txt")); 
        int sum = 0;
        while(in.hasNextInt()){
        sum = sum + (in.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```